# R c() creates a container the same class as the object concatenated. Correct?

Tags: r

If I concatenate a number(double):

```
x <- c(0.5,0.6)
```

What I appear to get is an object with no attributes, being of type double and a object container of numeric.

```
> x
[1] 0.5 0.6
> attributes(x)
NULL
> x
[1] 0.5 0.6
> type(x)
Error in type(x) : could not find function "type"
> typeof(x)
[1] "double"
> mode(x)
[1] "numeric"
```

I am a little confused in that the container created when using c() is of the same type as the object concatenated. Have I got this correct or fundamentally wrong?

Comment: It will not always create a container the same class as the original or the concatenated object. Two examples: (1) start with `x <- c(0.5)`, then append with `c(x, "A")` does not keep the class of the original object; similarly, (2) start with `x <- c("A")`, then append with `c(x, 0.5)` does not preserve the class of the appended object.

Comment: And one technicality: you say "class" but you're using `typeof`. The two are related, but while `typeof(Sys.time())` is `numeric`, if you do `class(Sys.time())` you'll get `[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`. It's not horribly wrong to infer some form of "class" by using `typeof`, but the two do not map one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric vectors are atomic objects in R, not containers, and all of the 3 objects below are numeric vectors having class `"numeric"` with the last two being identical.

In particular, numeric scalars are numeric vectors of length 1 and are not a separate class or type of object. We have not put `0.5` and `0.6` into a container `c(0.5, 0.6)` but rather have concatenated the vector `0.5` with the vector `0.6`.

```
# these are all numeric vectors
c(0.5,0.6)
c(0.5)
9.5

# the last two objects above are identical
identical(c(0.5), 0.5)
## [1] TRUE

# they are all of class "numeric"
class(c(0.5, 0.6))
## [1] "numeric"
class(0.5)
## [1] "numeric"
```

Lists are complex objects that can be regarded as containers but not numeric vectors.

```
# numeric vectors, but not lists, are atomic
is.atomic(c(0.5, 0.6))
## [1] TRUE
is.atomic(list(0.5, 0.6))
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Great answer, maybe this is a separate question. But still on the topic of atomic classes and vectors. Why is an empty vector() logical?

Comment: Because combining a logical with a logical gives another logical, combining a logical with a numeric gives another numeric and combining a logical with a character gives another character this allows c(x, `vector())` to have the class of `x` in all these cases without having to define some new special class for `vector()`.  Try these `class(c(TRUE, vector())`, `class(c(5, vector())`, `class(c("X", vector())`,  For the same reason `NA` is logical.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I can fully answer, but it may help to note there are no scalars in R, just vectors of length 1. When you use `c()`, you can concatenate two or more values to make longer vectors.

```
x <- 0
typeof(x)
#[1] "double"
length(x)
#[1] 1         # Now we have a double vector of length one.

y <- c(0)
typeof(y)
#[1] "double"
length(y)
#[1] 1         # Using c(), we made another double vector also of length one.

identical(x, y)  # are x and y identical objects?
#[1] TRUE        #  yep!

z <- c(0, 0)   # Now, use c() with two values
typeof(z)
#[1] "double"
length(z)
#[1] 2          # now we have a double vector of length two.

identical(x, z)
[1] FALSE
```